# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in EDGE for INTERNAL site

Tags: ssl-certificate, microsoft-edge, hsts

This has been written about many times, but I was not able to solve it

this is a small company with serveral (about 50) devices solely with internal IP with web server (like ESXI web, printer, ...)

upon opening the site
**https://myesxiserver.domain.local**
or
**https://myesxiserver**

I get
**NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

currently I type *thisisunsafe* and go ahead

I wanted to apply GPO/reg key in
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\HSTSPolicyBypassList`
...then and add hostnames (like "myesxiserver" without "domain.local").
...then restart Edge.
...then re-apply edge://policy

but it will still present the error

I will NOT use an internal PKI for this - this is a solution for a small enterprise, but not for a small company with only me responsible for everything.

I do not want to import the Autohority (the esxi itself) in every browser
I just want to tell the browser to ignore every certificate error from this device (only internal)
Is this not possible??

**what is still necessary?**

Answer (score 0):

Please note that HSTSPolicyBypassList

> only applies to static HSTS-preloaded entries (for
> example, "app", "new", "search", "play"). This policy does not prevent
> HSTS upgrades for servers that have dynamically requested HSTS
> upgrades using a Strict-Transport-Security response header.

You may check whether you have met these prerequisites.

For more information, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#hstspolicybypasslist.

Comment: I do not get it. It says supply "hostnames" and then only entries like "app", "play"...

I insistst a hostname to be a device name and not "play" or "app"

how do smaller companies handle this for their local devices? either PKI or "thisisunsafe" or browser switch??

Comment: What about deleting HSTS settings at edge://net-internals/#hsts? You can query with your hostname first, and then delete it. Of course, thisisunsafe is a good solution if you have only a small user base.

Comment: there already is no HSTS Entry.
I go to https://myesxiserver.domain.com whereas domain.com is in fact public known
so the self-signed certificate of myesxiserver for sure is not trustworthy

but I want to tell my browser to make an exception for this internal IP / website.
I can also open https://myesxiserver (without suffix) but it will still say
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I just do not get it. It is too much for security for me to handle

Comment: @Usermd181 So it looks like `thisisunsafe` is the best option for you. Another option is to use `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag, but it will also ignore other certificate errors.